# Supremum infimum on more general space

Tags: real-analysis

What is the definition of supremum and infimum on more general spaces, say $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: It doesn't exist.

Comment: @AlexM.can you elaborate more your comment? Why they don't exist?

Answer (score 1):

Once we have a partially ordered set, we can define supremum and infimum, as the same way we define in $\mathbb{R}$. Now, we can put a order in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. lexicographic order). The question is whether or not that supremum\infimum does exist.